# Text Flip using CSS Keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I am using CSS keyframes to animate two separate text.

The problem which I am facing is that the text of first span element ("first text") on 100% animation completion appears suddenly instead of second span element text fliping after the completion of "first text".

```css
.c--anim-btn {
  height: 40px;
  font: normal normal 700 1em/4em Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.c--anim-btn span {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.c-anim-btn {
  animation: rotateWord 3s linear infinite 0s;
}
.c--anim-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
  }
  25% {
    margin-top: 0rem;
  }
  40% {
    margin-top: -4rem;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -4rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="c--anim-btn">
  <span class="c-anim-btn">First Text</span>
  <span>Second Text</span>
</div>
```

---

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codecore/xdLL4faf/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the css property to the following, in order to keep the final state of the animation:

```
.c-anim-btn{
    animation: rotateWord 3s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 3.0s forwards
}
```

Comment: make sure to remove the "infinite" value, otherwise it won't work. Basically I just made the change on the fiddle, so it should work for you as well.

Comment: I want this to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a little your keyframes, may be this is what you want

```css
.c--anim-btn {
 height: 40px;
 font: normal normal 700 1em/4em Arial,sans-serif;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.c--anim-btn span {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}
.c-anim-btn{
 animation: rotateWord 3s linear infinite 0s;
}
.c--anim-btn span:nth-child(2){
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s; 
 -ms-animation-delay: 1.5s; 
 animation-delay: 1.5s; 
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
 0%, 25% {
   margin-top: 0rem;
 }
 40%, 75% {
   margin-top: -4rem;
 }
 100% {
  margin-top: 0rem; 
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="c--anim-btn">
  <span class="c-anim-btn">
   First Text
  </span>
  <span>
   Second Text
  </span>
 </div>
```